# List all From addresses by To addresses

Tags: gmail, imap

I have multiple email accounts and the messages are either forwarded to one Gmail account or I get them via POP/IMAP.
Now I want to simplify all that and use only one account and get rid of all others. I need to list all senders who wrote to each of my email addresses, so I can notify them about my new account or in case of websites, change my email address there.

I could search the emails like this:

> "to:myOldAddress@gmail.com"

and go through all emails. But unfortunately I have too many emails.

For the people out here who understand SQL, the query would be something like this:

```
select FromAddress from emailsTable
where ToAddress = "myOldAddress@gmail.com"
group by FromAddress
```

Another idea is to download all emails (Google allows you that) and scan them somehow. But I'm not sure though whether I can put it in an Excel or something.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to have an autoresponder (Vacation Responder under gmail general settings) on. By using an autoresponder to notify the new address and how the message is being forwarded to the new address; This will ensure that the notification of the new address will get to everyone who are still in contact with the old address. 
If someone tries to reach the old address using a new email, they will be notified by this method.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick Google search and this website came up. Looks interesting, quick look at the code and nothing malicious appears to be there, but I take no responsibility for it :)

> http://www.labnol.org/internet/extract-gmail-addresses/28037/

Another option you have is to put an out of office reply informing everyone that sends you a mail that you no longer use the mail, and you can give them your new email.
That's in GMail "Settings > General > Out of Office AutoReply:"